# How to toggle in Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

I have this HtML and java script code below. Its suppose to do this: when i click on yes, the textarea box that says why i like cs is suppose to show up and when i click on no, vice versa. but its not doing it, any help?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>forms.html</title>


 <h1> Welcome </h1>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jqueryui.
css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("img") .mouseover(function() {
$(this).attr("src", "pika2.jpg");
});
$("img").mouseout(function() {
$(this).attr("src", "pika1.jpg");
});

$("#show").hide();
$("#hide").hide();


$("#show").click(function(){
$("#hide").hide()
});
$("#hide").click(function(){
$("#show").show()
});
 });

</script>    
</head>

<body>  
<img src="pika1.jpg" alt="piakchu"/> 
<p> Please tell me who you are: </P>

<form action="sumbit.html">


 <p>
<label for="First Name">First name:</label>
<input type = "text" name="First Name" id="First Name" autofocus> 
</P>    



 <p>
<label for="Last Name">Last Name:</label>
<input type = "text" name="Last Name" id="Last Name" required > 
</P>    
 <div id="show">
<p> Do you like computer science: </p>
<p><input type="radio" name="list" value="yes" id="yes"/>
<label for="yes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="list" value="No" id="No"/>
<label for="No">No</label>
</P>
</div>
<div id="hide">
<p> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit your answers"/>
</p>

<p> Why don't you like computer science?: </p>

<textarea name="textarea" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Enter your text here (optional)">
</textarea>
</div>


</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Using Jquery Try $("xxx").toggle()

Comment: @mplungjan ya its a dv id on the text area code. its there but hidden until the user clicks on yes or no? but its not working , can help me fix it

Comment: @AkhilThayyil how? can u show me where my mistake is and how to fix it?

Comment: @shivaupadhyay could you make jsfiddle.net for better understanding?

Comment: instead of show and hide you can call toggle and can have a single event handler for both elements

Comment: I think you mistakenly put the submit button in the `div` that is to be shown or hidden.  You'll only be able to submit if you select no if you don't take it out.

Comment: how someone will click on yes or no when they are hidden too because you are hiding show and they are inside show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, the text box should show up for you!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img") .mouseover(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "pika2.jpg");
    });
    $("img").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "pika1.jpg");
    });

    $("#hide").hide();
    $(".yes").click(function(){
        $("#hide").show();
    });
    $(".no").click(function(){
        $("#hide").hide();
    });
});


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>  
<img src="pika1.jpg" alt="piakchu"/> 
<p> Please tell me who you are: </P>

<form action="sumbit.html">


 <p>
<label for="First Name">First name:</label>
<input type = "text" name="First Name" id="First Name" autofocus> 
</P>    



 <p>
<label for="Last Name">Last Name:</label>
<input type = "text" name="Last Name" id="Last Name" required > 
</P>    
 <div id="show">
<p> Do you like computer science: </p>
<p><input type="radio" name="list" value="yes" id="yes" class="yes"/>
<label for="yes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="list" value="No" id="No" class="no"/>
<label for="No">No</label>
</P>
</div>
<div id="hide">
<p> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit your answers"/>
</p>

<p> Why don't you like computer science?: </p>

<textarea name="textarea" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Enter your text here (optional)">
</textarea>
</div>


</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

your answer is ..........

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("img") .mouseover(function() {
  $(this).attr("src", "pika2.jpg");
 });
 $("img").mouseout(function() {
  $(this).attr("src", "pika1.jpg");
 });

 $("#hide").hide();
 $(".yes").click(function(){
  $("#hide").show();
 });
 $(".no").click(function(){
  $("#hide").hide();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>  
<img src="pika1.jpg" alt="piakchu"/> 
<p> Please tell me who you are: </P>

<form action="sumbit.html">


 <p>
<label for="First Name">First name:</label>
<input type = "text" name="First Name" id="First Name" autofocus> 
</P>    



 <p>
<label for="Last Name">Last Name:</label>
<input type = "text" name="Last Name" id="Last Name" required > 
</P>    
 <div id="show">
<p> Do you like computer science: </p>
<p><input type="radio" name="list" value="yes" id="yes" class="yes"/>
<label for="yes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="list" value="No" id="No" class="no"/>
<label for="No">No</label>
</P>
</div>
<div id="hide">
<p> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit your answers"/>
</p>

<p> Why don't you like computer science?: </p>

<textarea name="textarea" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Enter your text here (optional)">
</textarea>
</div>


</form>
</body>
```

Comment: i do not change your  image related code 
the only change in yes/no code

Comment: $("#yes") and $("#no") - please use the ID instead of the class

Answer (score 2):

You can use ternary operator for this purpose:
JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input:radio[name=list]").click(function () {
        $(this).val() == 'yes' ? $("#hide").show() : $("#hide").hide();
    });
});
```

or

as suggested in the comments below:

```
$("#hide").toggle(this.id=="yes");
```

Demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/wg6zx2wj/1/

Comment: or simpler `$("#hide").toggle(this.id=="yes");`

Answer (score 1):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/wg6zx2wj/

```
$("input:radio[name=list]").click(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();

    if (value == 'yes') {
        $("#hide").show()
    } else {
        $("#hide").hide()
    }
});
```

Comment: Also here you can use `$("#hide").toggle(this.id=="yes");`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I should change input type radio values to true or false.
Also, I think you are not writing the code that you want. For example, at first both divs are hidden and nothing make them appear (because radios are hidden too).

I think this is definitely a better approach to that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>forms.html</title>


 <h1> Welcome </h1>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jqueryui.
css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img") .mouseover(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "pika2.jpg");
    });
    $("img").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "pika1.jpg");
    });

    $("#whyNot").hide();

    $(':radio[name="list"]').change(function() {
      var like = $(this).filter(':checked').val();
      if (!JSON.parse(like)) {
          $("#whyNot").show();
      } else {
          $("#whyNot").hide();
      }
    });

 });

</script>    
</head>

<body>  
<img src="pika1.jpg" alt="piakchu"/> 
<p> Please tell me who you are: </P>

<form action="sumbit.html">

<p>
<label for="First Name">First name:</label>
<input type = "text" name="First Name" id="First Name" autofocus> 
</P>    
<div>
<label for="Last Name">Last Name:</label>
<input type = "text" name="Last Name" id="Last Name" required > 
</div>    
<div>
    <p> Do you like computer science: </p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="list" value="true"/>
    <label for="yes">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="list" value="false"/>
    <label for="No">No</label>
    </P>
</div>
<div id="whyNot">
    <p> Why don't you like computer science?: </p>
    <textarea name="textarea" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Enter your text here (optional)">
    </textarea>
</div>
<div> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit your answers"/>
</div>

</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This: Initially check the value of radio button and use `show();` and `hide();` method of jQuery for toggle the div element

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("input:radio[name=list]").click(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value == 'yes') {
            $("#hide").show();
        }
        else
        { 
          $("#hide").hide();
        }
        
      
    });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>  
<img src="pika1.jpg" alt="piakchu"/> 
<p> Please tell me who you are: </P>

<form action="sumbit.html">


 <p>
<label for="First Name">First name:</label>
<input type = "text" name="First Name" id="First Name" autofocus> 
</p>    



 <p>
<label for="Last Name">Last Name:</label>
<input type = "text" name="Last Name" id="Last Name" required > 
</p>    
 <div id="show">
<p> Do you like computer science: </p>
<p><input type="radio" name="list" value="yes" id="yes"/>
<label for="yes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="list" value="No" id="No"/>
<label for="No">No</label>
</P>
</div>
<div id="hide">
<p> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit your answers"/>
</p>

<p> Why don't you like computer science?: </p>

<textarea name="textarea" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Enter your text here (optional)">
</textarea>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: `$("#hide").toggle(value=="yes");` or `$("#hide").toggle(this.id=="yes");`